Importing Global Stylesheet Into gatsby-browser.js File Not Working
I'm updating a site built with Gatsby 5.1.  I want to add a global stylesheet to the project to expose styling to the entire website and saw that the best way to do it is to simply import it into the gatsby-browser.js file.  I did that however none of my styles are applying.  I tried running gatsby clean which got rid of the .cache and public folders and ran gatsby develop and the styles still didn't apply.  I even tried clearing everything again and running gatsby build then gatsby develop but that's not doing anything.
I've run into this type of issue importing stylesheets in other projects with different platforms and the problem was when the project was compiled the paths to the stylesheets no longer matched so I had to modify them to where the files would be after the project gets compiled so I tried changing
import './src/styles/global.css';

to
import '../src/styles/global.css';

and
import 'src/styles/global.css';

to see if that would make a difference.... it didn't.  I also looked through all the files in the .cache and public folders to see if I could find anything related to the site's styling so I could see how it was being handled to hopefully get some clue as to why mine aren't loading but didn't see anything that seemed css related.
One of the things I'm doing is rebuilding all the components from scratch to eliminate the material design components so I'm wondering if maybe those packages are doing something under the hood that forces their styling to take priority.
As of right now my global.css file just has a class to make text orange just so I can see if it works and I'm also importing two other stylesheets into it.  Does anybody know what the problem could be?
